# Laravel parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CLASS, expecting T_STRING in artisan

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

## I checked my php version:

> PHP 7.0.27 (cli) (built: Jan 23 2018 09:07:32) ( NTS )
>   Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
>   Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies

[image: Image php Version here]

## But this is the error that appears when doing cron job

> **Parse error**:  syntax error, unexpected T_CLASS, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or '$' in **/path_to_project/artisan** on line **31**
>   X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.29
>   Content-type: text/html

## and I used this to test this code

```
<?php 
class Foo{}
echo Foo::class;

?>
```

The output is `:Foo`

## artisan file

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
require __DIR__.'/bootstrap/autoload.php';

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/app.php';


$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel::class);

$status = $kernel->handle(
$input = new Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput,
new Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput
);

$kernel->terminate($input, $status);

exit($status);
```

I run it like this:

```
* * * * * php /path_to_project/artisan schedule:run >> /path_to_project/log.txt
* * * * * php-cli -q /path_to_project/artisan  schedule:run >> /path_to_project/log.txt
```

How do I resolve this error?

Comment: so what is on the line 31? could you post the relevant snippet? It's hard to see where error is if you don't show relevant code.

Comment: updated 
error not cuz code 
that artisan file belong to laravel

Comment: quick search discovers many similar questions, all point to old PHP version: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32205590/laravel-parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-t-class-expecting-t-string-or-t-v

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel parse error: syntax error, unexpected T\_CLASS, expecting T\_STRING or T\_VARIABLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32205590/laravel-parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-t-class-expecting-t-string-or-t-v)

Comment: i know but my php version 7.0.27

Comment: can you verify that by adding `phpinfo();` in the artisan file?

Comment: and i post the version in question 
i searched in questions that u menthioned

Comment: phpinfo()
PHP Version => 7.0.27

Comment: Ask your host. I'd guess your CLI is configured to use a particular PHP, perhaps via `.profile` or `.bash_profile`, and that `cron` doesn't use that profile.

Answer (score 1):

How do you run your code? Whatever is running it uses old PHP version.

It says it right here:

> `X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.29`

see similar question on how to fix it:
[Laravel parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CLASS, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32205590/laravel-parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-t-class-expecting-t-string-or-t-v)

Also this answer suggests using `php-cli` to run your code instead of `php`:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41776870/7417402
This might explain why you get different versions.

Comment: how do you run your code? what is the command you are using? are you running it via cron?